# Kubelet incorrectly thinks disk is full

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubelet

I'm having issues with kubelet removing docker images because it believes the disk is full:

```
Dec 29 18:00:14 hostname kubelet: I1229 18:00:14.548513   13836 image_gc_manager.go:300] [imageGCManager]: Disk usage on image filesystem is at 85% which is over the high threshold (85%). Trying to free 2160300032 bytes down to the low threshold (80%).
```

However, the partition that docker uses is 1TB and has plenty of space:

```
$ docker info
...
Docker Root Dir: /scratch/docker

$ df -k /scratch
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      976283900 234476968 741806932  25% /scratch
```

It seems kubelet is finding the disk usage for my main partition on `/`, which also happens to be the partition kubelet itself is installed on:

```
$ df -k /
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p2  52403200 44032936   8370264  85% /
```

So where does kubelet get information about available disk space? I assumed it was using the docker daemon, but based on what I'm seeing the two apps are looking at different partitions. Is there a configuration I can set, or is does it just default to its own partition when doing the disk space check?

This is using Kubernetes 1.17.4 on RedHat 7 and docker 18.06.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this Mike? I am facing exactly the same problem and didn't find anything that helped me on that github issue.

Comment: @mightflypig It's been a while and I think our SAs have since fixed it, but I think our specific case was to do with kubelet looking at a default partition where we didn't actually run any pods. It was something like yum cache filling up disk space, so I think I simply worked around it at the time by setting up a cron to clear the yum cache nightly. Probably not helpful for your case but that's about all I remember.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of weird edge case bugs in there, see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/66961 as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'm not alone. I'll add a comment to that issue with my specific case.